# Portable docker daemon for deterministic CI builds

Tags: docker, bazel

We are looking to make use of Docker to run integration tests within CI builds (with [Bazel](http://bazel.build)).
We need to support Debian as well as MacOS.

In order to guarantee build correctness, and ensure determinism and portability, we cannot rely on the host having a running docker daemon. The build needs to come with its own docker daemon.
What is the best way to achieve this? Is there a standard “portable” docker binary?
If not, what do you think would be the right approach to implement this?
In linux systems, I imagine this would be relatively simple, as we would just need to download the binaries and run.
In MacOS, I guess we would need to bundle it with [hyperkit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit).

Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: I'll ping [@mattmoor](https://github.com/mattmoor), owner of the [Docker Bazel rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker) to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of building Docker images, you should look at `bazelbuild/rules_docker` (disclaimer: I wrote/own them).  They implement the only properly deterministic Docker *builds* of which I'm aware (at least to Bazel's standard).

They do this by avoiding Dockerfile and the Docker daemon (which most other approaches use), as it is unclear these can produce deterministic artifacts.  This avoids the root requirement too, which is nice.

However, you specifically asked about *testing*, which tl;dr we have not solved.

[@ittaiz](https://github.com/ittaiz) is also interested in this and started [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/issues/241) Github issue for discussing it.  Would you mind moving the discussion there?

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Apologies if I was unclear or stepping on toes here. I'm working with @ittaiz on this and I'm aware of the github issue. The purpose of my question was more to get the Docker people involved in the discussion, because what we really need is a portable docker daemon.